# Sending DM to user in Flask python with discord.py

Tags: python, flask, discord.py

So I am trying to create a vote webhook for my discord bot with the flask module, but apparently importing discord.py and flask in the same file don't really go good together. When I run my code, it just shows `RuntimeError: Event loop stopped before Future completed.`. Here is my code:

```py
#setup code
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def respond():
    data = request.json
    auth = request.headers
    if auth["Authorization"] == "my_auth":
         user = client.get_user(user_id)
         await user.send('Thank you for voting for me! Make sure you vote again in 12 hours!')
    return Response(status=200)
```

That doesn't work, because you can't do `await` outside of a `async` function, so I replaced  `await user.send('Thank you for voting for me! Make sure you vote again in 12 hours!')` with   `client.loop.create_task(user.send('Thank you for voting for me! Make sure you vote again in 12 hours!'))` which is what gave me the error `RuntimeError: Event loop stopped before Future completed.`. I was told that using Flask is not letting discord.py run, and I do not know how to fix that. So can you please help me figure out how to DM a user when the webhook is fired?

Information about webhook:
[Click Here to see the request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyL9b.png)

Versions:
Python: 3.8.5
Discord.py: 1.4.1
Flask: 1.1.2

EDIT: I realized that this actually works when I type `flask run` in terminal, but it doesn't work with `gunicorn app:app`. Since typing `flask run` runs a development server and not what I should actually use , I run `gunicorn app:app` which is what gives me `RuntimeError: Event loop stopped before Future completed.`

Comment: Are you using celery for your app? To implement the async task in flask, you should use celery.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding async in function definition.

```py
async def respond():
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't fix the error, and it still shows ```RuntimeError: Event loop stopped before Future completed.``` but thank you for responding! Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you using celery?

Comment: As a matter of fact, celery is the best solution for the async task implementation